# How does this functional component using react hooks get its parameters?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was just going through a React project that uses hooks and function based components and came across the following peice of code, basically a component that looks like so:

```
const App = ({ init, isLoading }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);
  const [isMobile, setisMobile] = useState(null);
  console.log('isMobile');
  console.log(isMobile);
  // Set amount of items to show on slider based on the width of the element
  const changeMobile = () => {
    window.matchMedia('(max-width: 80em)').matches
      ? setisMobile(true)
      : setisMobile(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    changeMobile();
    window.addEventListener('resize', changeMobile);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', changeMobile);
  }, []);

  .........
};
```

The line of code i am talking about can be seen [HERE](https://github.com/fidalgodev/movie-library-react/blob/master/src/containers/App.js#L98) too.

Usually i am used to seeing props being passed to function based components, but what i see here is very different , also where are these properties being passed from ? I.E. `{ init, isLoading }` ?

Also because if i see how the `<App />` component is being called [HERE](https://github.com/fidalgodev/movie-library-react/blob/master/src/index.js#L28), i don't see any props being passed. So how exactly does this functional component get its parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look further down the file, you can see that what the file actually exports is a decorated version of `<App />`. It's using a *[higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)* from [`react-redux`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) which provides the props that you see.

```js
const mapStateToProps = ({ geral }) => {
  return { isLoading: geral.loading };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { init }
)(App);
```

`react-redux` internally uses [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to access the redux store, which is where it actually gets the values. It may be helpful to think of React's context as kind of "invisible props" that get passed down to every component that's a child of the `<Context.Provider>` component, and accessed via `<Context.Consumer>` or `useContext`.

Answer (score 2):

`props` is an `Object` and can be destructured. Tha't what's happening.

```
const Component = ({ init, isLoading }) =>{}
```

Is short for

```
const Component = props =>{
    const { init, isLoading } = props
}
```

You destructuring `init` and `isLoading` from `props` and exposing then in your component's scope

Comment: +1 , i understand destructing is at work here but i don't see anything being passed to <App /> either https://github.com/fidalgodev/movie-library-react/blob/master/src/index.js#L28

Comment: The parameters have values? Or are `undefined`

Comment: `init` is a function and `isLoading` is boolean.

Comment: In the repo you linked, isLoading comes mapStateToProps and connect. Ie, it comes from a redux store

Comment: @NicholasTower , Makes sense yes thats what i was confused about. :P